# Can't boot to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot

Perviouly I used the 16.04 version of Ubuntu which worked perfectly. Recently, I installed 20.04 but after the initial restart I can't find Ubuntu from the boot manager of my motherboard.

I chose to install it to a separate partition as I did before  with 16.04 version. I was then able to boot it to Ubuntu by choosing it from the boot manager of the motherboard. But now I can't find it there.

What to do if I want to bring it back to the boot manager??

Thanks all.

Edit: I’m using UEFI currently.

Comment: Add details.  Dualbooting from what?  Windows?  Are you in Legacy mode or UEFI?  During the install did you select where to install Grub?  Make a Boot Repair disk and it will most likely fix the issue.

Comment: I'm in UEFI currently. At first I didn't noticed the grub bootloader installation location. I successfully solved the issue by following proper instructions. I was being too dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved the problem. At first I didn't selected any grub bootloader location while installing. A youtube tutorial helped me. Then by changing the boot order (not drive order) I managed to bring the grub bootloader.